# Salvar imagens no banco de dados e depois mostrar em um listview

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Quero salvar imagens pelo `sqllite` e depois exibí-las por uma `listView`, mas não sei como faço. Alguém pode dar uma ajuda? Não precisa mostrar linhas de código quero só saber a lógica que devo seguir ou quais classes usar.

Comment: Normalmente é salvo somente o caminho da imagem no banco, não a imagem. Você quer salvar a imagem mesmo?

Comment: Tem o tipo de campo blob, vc pode usar para salvar a imagem como um array de bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nao aconselho você a salvar a imagem directamente no campo de dados mas sim salvar a imagem em uma pasta dentro da sua aplicação e copiar e salvar a Uri(O caminho ate a imagem) no Banco de dados do mesmo jeito que o whatsapp faz com as imagens que você recebe de uma conversa.

O procedimento seria o seguinte:
-Baixa a Imagem saiba qual o Uri. resposta bacana aqui :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549421/how-to-download-and-save-an-image-in-android
-Guarde a Uri no banco de dados.
-No momento de carregar os dados para a lista, você pega toda a informação incluindo o Uri.
-Carrega a imagem pelo Uri utilizando uma lib : Picasso, Volley , Glide etc