# Como fazer uma referência de imagem?

Tags: java, android

Quero fazer app simples onde o usuário selecione uma imagem do cartão SD e em seguida possa salvar a sua referência no sqlite para poder ser exibida em uma listview, mas ainda não sei como posso fazer essa referência.

Comment: E se o usuário excluir a imagem do SD?

Comment: Se estiver a obter a imagem da Galeria usando Intent.ACTION_PICK veja esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69353/2541)

Comment: Compartilhe suas tentativas, seus códigos, seus erros assim fica mais fácil te direcionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para você fazer isso você primeiro teria que fazer com o que o utilizador tenha obrigatoriamente essa pasta com as imagens que você deseja mostrar. Como quer fazer uma app simples e e uma demo, aconselho que faça o caminho contrario:
1- Escolha vários links de imagens que você quer guardar na pasta(Urls de sites). 
2- Dentro do aplicativo, utilizando AsyncTasks ou outro mecanismo, descarregue as imagens, crie a pasta onde vai querer guardar as fotos no SD, e salve as imagens la.
3- Assim que confirmar que as imagens estao salvadas, ou a medida que voce vai salvando na pasta, voce pode pegar a Uri(**caminho ate ao local on a imagem esta guardada**) e guardar na sua BD.
4 - Quando quiser mostrar em uma lista ou algo do género, você só precisa ir a BD, carregar todas as Uris e utilizando bibliotecas como Picasso, Volley etc, você pode carregar as imagens para um ImageView.

Respondi uma pergunta similar que se encontra aqui: [Salvar imagens no banco de dados e depois mostrar em um listview](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105070/salvar-imagens-no-banco-de-dados-e-depois-mostrar-em-um-listview/105101#105101)